# Combine multiple HTML CSS for a building a new page

Tags: java, javascript, css

I am looking for information about how to make a HTML page out of two separate smaller HTML patterns per say. Both these patterns have thier own HTML, CSS and Java script. I need to combine them and render them as a single HTML page. Any pointers to any available utility to do so or any pointers to build such a tool

Thanks
VB

Comment: It really depends how you want the finished page to look. Your favorite text-editor should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just get the two pages to display at the same time, put each page into an `<iframe>` in a "wrapper" HTML page. This helps prevent conflicts between the two pages. Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head><!-- snip --></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="page1.html"></iframe>
        <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```